# How to locate a span with a specific text in Selenium? (Using Java)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble locating a span element in Selenium using java.

the HTML looks like:

```html
<div class="settings-padding">
<span>Settings</span>
</div>
```

And I've tried the following with no luck:

```
By.xpath("span[.='Settings']")
```

and

```
By.xpath("span[text()='Settings']")
```

and

```
By.cssSelector("div[class='settings-padding']"))
```

as well as some other similar attempts. Could you point me to the best method to do this? As it stands I constantly get "Unable to locate element" error in eclipse.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your all `xpath` are looks OK, Just some [syntactically](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) incorrect. you are missing `//` in your `xpath`

The correct `xpath` are as below :-

```
By by = By.xpath("//span[.='Settings']")
```

Or

```
By by = By.xpath("//span[text()='Settings']")
```

Or

```
By by = By.xpath("//div[@class='settings-padding']/span"))
```

Or you can use `cssSelector` as :-

```
By by = By.cssSelector("div.settings-padding > span"))
```

Using anyone of the above By locator you can locate element as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement el = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(by));
```

Hope it helps...:)

Answer (score 2):

For the element below

```html
<span class="test-button__text">
    Test Text
</span>
```

The following solution works for me

```java
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'test-button__text') and text()='Test Text']")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in C# (Java equivalent assumed but not tested):

> C#

```
By by = By.CssSelector("span[class='settings-padding']"))
```

> Java

```
By by = By.cssSelector("span[class='settings-padding']"))
```