# How do I locate a Span in HTML with specific text "Update" using Selenium

Tags: selenium, element, locate

I'm trying to find 'span' element with a text 'update' within. I'm using following code to do so.

`<<span class="update-btn-text">Update</span>`

This fails and selenium is unable to find the element. How can I find an element with specific text with `span`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to locate a span with a specific text in Selenium? (Using Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534241/how-to-locate-a-span-with-a-specific-text-in-selenium-using-java)

Comment: Was my answer useful? If yes -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Comment: @Marvin Can you provide the `HTML` code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of the following locators.

Using className:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("update-btn-text")).click();
```

Using CSS selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.update-btn-text")).click();
```

Using XPath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class="update-btn-text"])).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Update']")).click();
```